# Create Slider with Closure

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, google-closure-library

I'm trying to implement a content slider with Closure, using the goog.fx.dom.Slide function. The idea is to be able to drag a slide bar on the bottom of a container div, and have the container div slide accordingly as the slider is moved by the user. I get no errors on the console with my current setup, but the container div doesn't slide anywhere.

HTML:

```
<div id="sliderContainer"> 
<div id="slider">
    <div id="s-h">
        <div class="sliderBox"></div>
        ...
        <div class="sliderBox"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS (fired from a click on the slider, which works). A and B are the destination values (for example, 100 and 0, since I only need horizontal scrolling):

```
function slide(a, b) {
    // a and b are coordinates provided b
    var el = document.getElementById('s-h');
    var duration = 1000;
    var x = el.offsetLeft;
    var y = 0;
    var anim = new goog.fx.dom.Slide(el, [x, y], [a, b], duration,goog.fx.easing.easeOut);
    anim.play();}
```

Any advice, or anything obviously wrong?

Comment: are you looking for this ? - http://closure-library.googlecode.com/git-history/e26392235d9120d8b63eb6a59465fc4462d493e9/closure/goog/demos/slider.html

Answer (score 0):

```
require('goog.ui.Slider');
```

// then later

```
var slider = new goog.ui.Slider();
slider.render();
```

// but you also have to add css

```
.goog-slider-thumb {
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  /* background image */
}

.goog-slider-horizontal {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  /* color, etc... */
}
```